# What is the dimension of the orthogonal complement of an one-dimensional subspace in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbf u$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^n$. If $V=\{c\mathbf u: c \in \mathbb R\}$ then $\dim V^\bot \ge n-1.$ Why is this statement true? For orthogonal complements the following relationship holds: $\dim V + \dim V^\bot = n,$ and since $V$ is a line it is one dimensional, so shouldn't $\dim V^\bot = n-1$? Why is it greater than or equal to?

Comment: What if $u = 0$?

Comment: @Coriolanus, such a pick it doesn't give a 1-dimensional subspace.

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: MathJax was used quite badly here. See my edits for proper usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\dim V^\perp = n-1$ then $\dim V^\perp \ge n-1.$

But in one instance you have $\dim V^\perp = n,$ namely when $\mathbf u = \mathbf 0.$